# Why a postgreSQL timestamp with time zone at a certain time zone is printed without the time zone

Tags: postgresql, timestamp, timezone

When I ask PostgreSQL for a timestamp with time zone *at a certain time zone*, it does not print the time zone:

```
SELECT now()::timestamp WITH TIME ZONE AT TIME ZONE 'CST';

          timezone          
----------------------------
 2023-11-08 06:00:28.983353
(1 row)
```

Whereas:

```
SELECT now()::timestamp WITH TIME ZONE;

              now              
-------------------------------
 2023-11-08 12:01:00.704341+00
(1 row)
```

Does print the time zone (`+00`)?

Why?

I was naturally expecting a time zone indication with the first query.
Or, when asked `without`:

```
SELECT now()::timestamp WITHOUT TIME ZONE AT TIME ZONE 'CST';

           timezone            
-------------------------------
 2023-11-08 18:08:25.911371+00
(1 row)
```

it does print it.

Comment: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-ZONECONVERT